# Using doxygen to create documentation for existing C# code with XML comments

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen, xml-documentation

I've read *everywhere* that doxygen is the way to go for generating documentation for C# code.  I've got a single interface that I want to document first (baby steps), and it already has the XML comments (///) present.

Because of the vast number of posts and information available (including doxygen.org) that say these comments are already supported, I'm surprised that when I run doxywizard, I get errors like "warning: Compound Company::Product::MyInterface is not documented".

This leads me to believe that I have somehow misunderstood XML documentation (hopefully not, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) I am talking about the right thing), or I have misconfigured doxywizard.

I first ran doxywizard via the Wizard tab, and specified that I want to support C#/Java.  When I run it, my HTML page is blank, presumably because of the previously-mentioned warnings.  I then tried specifying a single file via the Expert tab and ran again -- same behavior.

Can anyone tell me what switch or setting I'm missing to get doxygen to generate the HTML?

Here's an example of what a documented property/method looks like in my interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieve the version of the device
/// </summary>
String Version { get; }

/// <summary>
/// Does something cool or really cool
/// </summary>
/// <param name="thing">0 = something cool, 1 = something really cool</param>
void DoSomething( Int32 thing);
```

I do have a comment above the interface, like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// MyInterface
/// </summary>
public interface MyInterface {...}
```

Comment: Dave, do you have a comment above the line where the interface is declared?

Comment: @Eric yes I do... I have updated my question to show the comment.  Perhaps I need some special doxygen syntax there?

Comment: Hmmm.... That all looks fine. All I can think of is that there are a bunch of EXTRACT_ parameters. Try turning them all to YES. What you are trying to do will work. There is just something missing. There is a little more trial-and-error required with doygen that I'd like.

Comment: @Eric haha, good timing!  I *just* posted about that after reading something about EXTRACT_ALL.  Enabling that made it work, though I feel it should have worked even with that setting disabled.  Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 12):

I think I've figured it out.  The doxygen manual says that EXTRACT_ALL = 0 is the default setting, and in this case "will only generate documentation for documented members, files, classes and namespaces".  Now, I *thought* that I had documented them properly, but apparently not.  I just enabled EXTRACT_ALL, and the warnings went away, and I got documentation for my interface!  I read up on the "special documentation blocks", thinking I was missing something (thanks to Eric Farr's comment), but it made no mention of doing anything special for C# code, so I am under the assumption that the default value for EXTRACT_ALL should have still worked.

Comment: Glad you found it. Doxygen can be frustrating at times, but it's the best free tool for what you want to do.